# (Asymptotic) Cycle structure in a random permutation given total number of cycles?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, random-permutations

A random $N$-permutation is the one drawn uniformly from all possible permutations on $N$ points.

We know that the expected number of cycles of length $\ell$ in a random $N$-permutation, $\mathbb{E}C_\ell(N)$, is $1/\ell$, and we know the joint distribution of those $C_\ell(P_N)$-s converges to joint distribution of independent Poisson random variables $Z_\ell$-s of intensity $1/\ell$ resp.

But do we have any results on the distribution of $(C_\ell(P_N))_{\ell\le N}$, or the limiting distribution of it, given the total number of cycles $\sum_{\ell\le N}C_{\ell}(P_N)$?

Or even more generally the (asymptotic) distribution of $(C_\ell(P_N))_{\ell\le M}$ given  $\sum_{\ell\le M}C_{\ell}(P_N)$ with $M\to\infty$?